# Mockito InvalidUseOfMatchersException, when trying to unit test method with custom Callback as a parameter

Tags: java, android, mockito, mvp

I am learning Android MVP architecture and trying to test some methods with Mockito/JUnit. I was learning from this tutorial:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex

I have a problem with testing the Presenter method in my Android MVP architecture type app.

Here is my Presenter class:

```
public class ForgotPasswordPresenter implements ForgotPasswordMVP.Presenter{
private ForgotPasswordMVP.View view;
private ForgotPasswordMVP.Model model;


public ForgotPasswordPresenter(FirebaseAuthService firebaseAuthService, ForgotPasswordMVP.Model model) {
    this.model = model;
}

@Override
public void setView(ForgotPasswordMVP.View view) {
    this.view = view;
}

@Override
public void sendButtonClicked() {

    if(view != null) {
        view.showProgressBar();
        model.sendEmail(view.getEmail(), new 
        ForgotPasswordMVP.Model.SendForgotEmailCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onEmailSent(boolean sent) {
                if(sent) {
                    view.hideProgressBar();
                    view.showEmailSent();
                }
                else{
                //show some error on UI
                }
            }
        });
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the contract interface for the MVP.Model structure. I defined custom Callback:

```
   interface Model{
   interface SendForgotEmailCallback {
        void onEmailSent(boolean sent);
    }

    void sendEmail(String email, @NonNull SendForgotEmailCallback SendForgotEmailCallback) ;
}
```

In my model i do stuff like this, I am just using Firebase to reset the password:

```
public class ForgotPasswordModel implements ForgotPasswordMVP.Model{

private FirebaseAuthService firebaseAuthService;

public ForgotPasswordModel(FirebaseAuthService firebaseAuthService) {
    this.firebaseAuthService = firebaseAuthService;
}

@Override
public void sendEmail(String email, @NonNull final SendForgotEmailCallback SendForgotEmailCallback) {
    firebaseAuthService.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    SendForgotEmailCallback.onEmailSent(true);
                }
                else{
                    SendForgotEmailCallback.onEmailSent(false);
                }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Now, I want to test the method responsible for sending the Email, just the send button clicked. Here is my test prototype:

```
public class ForgotPasswordPresenterTest {

@Mock
ForgotPasswordMVP.Model model;

@Mock
ForgotPasswordMVP.View view;

@Mock
FirebaseAuthService firebaseAuthService;

@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<ForgotPasswordMVP.Model.SendForgotEmailCallback> sendForgotEmailCallbackArgumentCaptor;


private ForgotPasswordPresenter forgotPasswordPresenter;

@Before
public void setupForgotPasswordPresenter(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    forgotPasswordPresenter = new ForgotPasswordPresenter(firebaseAuthService, model);
    forgotPasswordPresenter.setView(view);
}

  @Test
public void sendButtonClicked_shouldShowEmailSent(){

    when(view.getEmail()).thenReturn("test@mail.com");

    forgotPasswordPresenter.sendButtonClicked();

    verify(model).sendEmail(view.getEmail(), sendForgotEmailCallbackArgumentCaptor.capture());
    sendForgotEmailCallbackArgumentCaptor.getValue().onEmailSent(true);

    verify(view).showEmailSent();

}
```

}

So, when it comes to verify(model).sendEmail... it crashes and this Exception from Mockito comes up:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
>   Invalid use of argument matchers!
>   2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
>   -> at com.example.app.ui.login.ForgotPasswordPresenterTest.sendButtonClicked_shouldShowEmailSent(ForgotPasswordPresenterTest.java:53)
>   This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
>       //incorrect:
>       someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
>   When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
>   For example:
>       //correct:
>       someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.

Can anyone help me with this? I am beginner, trying to figure it out, but really don't have a clue for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are capturing the argument using `capture()` (which is treated as a matcher), you have to use `eq` for all the other raw values in your `verify`. In your test `view.getEmail()` returns raw value ("test@mail.com"),  so your verify would change to this :

```
verify(model).sendEmail(eq(view.getEmail()), sendForgotEmailCallbackArgumentCaptor.capture());
```

Notice that you will now verify `view.getEmail()` wrapped with `eq`.

A good thing to remember is : If you use a matcher for any of the method arguments, then all arguments should be verified with matchers (use `eq` for raw values).

Comment: Thanks it worked! I can accept your answer only after 9 minutes, thanks

Comment: I have now the same problem, when i have 2 parameters. https://gist.github.com/oksett/78b76637257851d326ac8f8f5b93b201 Can you help me?

Comment: It should work the same as before no matter how many parameters you have.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not, it is the same error. The only difference is that, i test the method with 3 parameters, and not 2 as before. Any idea?

Comment: Does the error say "3 matchers expected, 1 recorded" or something like that? Looking from your snippet, it should work

Comment: It say: 0 matchers expected, 1 recorded:

Comment: That means that you don't need `eq`, so why did you put `captor` as the third argument? Try removing the two `eq` and see if it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149466/discussion-between-abubakkar-and-okset).